What is this movie with a man who can see that people are about to die?
A few years ago, I saw a movie on the tv about a man that lost his wife and daughter, killed by some guy.
After this he starts to see when people are about to die.
After some deaths, he decides to help these people, and starts saving them.
Then he falls in love with a girl he just saved from death.
Meanwhile, some entities show up in his life.
He meets the murderer of his wife and daughter, and he tells him he had interfered in a superior order. And now these entities claim that he should put things in place, and kill himself and those people he saved. This includes the girl he fell in love with.

Welcome to the community. What language was the movie in? Do you know the year and country of its production? In the plot, what location was the movie set in? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

I think it might be called hallucination or something such. Ive seen that movie. The mans family is killed in a diner by a shooter. Maybe with John Cusack?

Could be The Frighteners

After a tragic car accident that kills his wife, a man discovers he can communicate with the dead to con people. However, when a demonic spirit appears, he may be the only one who can stop it from killing the living and the dead. 






Following the accident, Frank gained the power to see ghosts.
Frank's ability to foretell the murders puts him under suspicion.
Frank realizes that Bartlett's ghost, with Patricia's help, was responsible for his wife's death. (Wikipedia)



If Nathan Fillion plays the main character, then this movie is White Noise 2: The Light.
"After witnessing the murder of his wife and young son at the hands of Henry Caine, who then turned a gun on himself, Abe Dale (Nathan Fillion) is so distressed that he attempts to take his own life. A near death experience follows that leaves Abe with the ability to identify those who are about to die. He acts on these premonitions to save three people fro death, among them a nurse met during his recovery, Sherry Clarke."
It is revealed that all the people that are saved that were "marked" for death are "possessed" with the compulsion to kill other people. Which is what happened with the person that killed his wife and son.

Wife and son murdered by man Check
Main character gains ability to see who is about to die Check
Main character's romantic interest is among the people marked for death that he saved, that he must kill to restore the "natural order" Check


Good match!  I think it just might be the right answer.
